# Disabled submit button if inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I have here is a ajax checking the availability of information in database. But what my problem is I want to disabled the submit button if the others inputs/textboxes are empty. I add the disable function in my ajax but when one of the textbox has a value the disabled isn't working. Any help will appreciate.

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input[type="text"]').change(function() 
{
var pr = $("#pr").val();
var msgbox = $("#status");
var txtbxs = $('.inputs').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check_ajax.php",
    data: "pr="+pr,
    success: function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
    if(msg == 'OK' && txtbxs !== '')
    {
        msgbox.html('<img src="css/available.png" align="absmiddle">');
        $("#save").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else
    {
    $("#save").prop("disabled",true);
    msgbox.html(msg);
    }
   }); 
   }  
  });
return false;
});
});
</script>

<tr>
    <td>PR #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pr" id="pr" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span id="status"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Date1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker inputs" autocomplete="off" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Date2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker inputs" autocomplete="off" readonly></td>
</tr>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="save">
```

**Check_ajax.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pr']))
{
$pr = $_POST['pr'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("select id, pr from pr_list where pr='$pr'");
if(($sql->num_rows)>= 1)
{
echo '<STRONG>'.$pr.'</STRONG> is already in use.';
}
elseif($pr == '') {
echo 'Fund is Empty';
}
else
{
echo 'OK';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: please define "isn't working"

Comment: The "disablement" is forced by the browser. The browser knows when to disable when the "disabled" attribute is set with any value (or no value). To update an attribute using a DOM node (usually findable in jQuery land via `$node[0]`) using its `setAttribute()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxcomplete` isn't really the right thing to use here, `ajaxcomplete` adds an event listener for every ajax call you make but you only need to check the message when this ajax call is successful.

It would still work though but for the `msg` variable having no scope whithin the `ajaxcomplete` function. Here is one way I would do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // I've moved these variables here to give them global-ish scope
    // I've also added a variable to assign your save button to
    var msgbox = $("#status"),
        saveButton = $("#save");


    $('input[type="text"]').change(function() 
    {
        var pr = $("#pr").val(),
            txtbxs = $('.inputs'),
            empty = true;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check_ajax.php",
            data: "pr="+pr,
            success: function(msg){

                 console.log(msg)

                 // loop through the txtbxs and check for emptiness :)
                 $.each(txtbxs, function(key, box) {
                    if (box.val() != "") {
                       empty = false;
                    } else {
                       empty = true;
                    }
                 });

                 if(msg == 'OK' && !empty) {
                    msgbox.html('<img src="css/available.png" align="absmiddle">');
                    saveButton.prop("disabled",false);
                 } else {
                    saveButton.prop("disabled",true);
                    msgbox.html(msg);
                 }
            } // END OF SUCCESS FUNCTION
        });// END OF AJAX CALL
    }); 
});// END OF DOCUMENT READY
```

Another thing I'm not sure about is that when you do your if statement and have `txtbxs != ''` are you trying to check that the boxes aren't empty or that the variable is not empty.

The way you have it set that the you are checking for the variable to be empty, if you are wanting to check that the `txtbxs` have a value then you want a some different code

Comment: I try it but why it always get 1 msg, the msg was not right even the value I entered was available.

Comment: @user3631428 I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.  Could you explain what message you are getting and what the output of console.log(msg) is

Comment: I think it because you moved up the variable so my #pr value is always get empty. I add my ajax in question

Comment: @user3631428 I've edited my answer moving pr down. I did not notice that this was your call data. Too focused on the structure and not the lkogic

Comment: I try your code but also it allows to submit even the other textboxes is empty. ( Noted, I can't figure out why this happens, when I try to enter in pr field and the value is available the message in my msgbox is OK not the image, but when I try to input in one of the textboxes the image show up and the submit button was not disabled.) Why is that?

Comment: txtbxs != '' doesn't check if the textboxes are empty, that is why I asked the question at the bottom of my post.  I wasn't sure what you wanted.

Comment: Yah from your answer, yes I want the txtbxs to check if the value was empty.

Comment: so How I can check if the textboxes is empty?

Comment: @user3631428 I've edited my answer, you have to loop through each textbox and check if the value != ""

Comment: I saw that there's error in your closing brackets, if I'm right? I fix that but I got this ReferenceError: empty is not defined.

Comment: also got this TypeError: box.val is not a function. I have here 2 jquery 1.5v and 1.9v. I changed $ into jQuery_1_9_1 but I got this TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj. :(

Comment: @user3631428 the type error is because I'm half asleep and didn't change the txtbxs variable. I've re-re-re-edited the code and that should work. I've also fixed the missing brace in the if statement and moved the empty assingment into the change, this should reset it every time now for ease.

Comment: yah I got this, the only problem is this TypeError: box.val is not a function.